# Markov Chain - Stochastic Processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, stochastic-analysis

Let us consider an answering service in which the customer must pass through two servers, which we call A and B. Suppose that the customers arrive at the location according to a rate 2 Poisson process and that enter the system only through server A. If upon arrival, the client finds server A busy, he leaves immediately. Otherwise, it enters the system, being served initially by A. Upon completing its service in A, if server B is busy, the customer leaves. Otherwise it goes to attendance of server B. Let us imagine that the attendance time of server A is exponential with rate 3 and that the attendance time of server B is exponential with rate 2.

A) Formulate a Markov chain to model this situation. It is suggested to take states that indicate the busy servers. Find the stationary distribution of the chain.

If you observe this process for a very long time, what can you say about:

B) The proportion of customers entering the system?

C) The proportion of clients arriving at server B?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I don't even know how to start. I'm really confused :/

Comment: Hint: Define the states, and find the transition probabilities which can then be uses to make the transition matrix $P$.